# Generics in a recursive method

Tags: java, generics, types, recursion

My architecture has some classes XMLElement (defining as type inner type of its children)

Why does not compile this?

```
private static <T extends XMLElement<U>, U extends XMLElement<?>> T recursiveFilter(T root){
        T filteredRoot = root;
        //Some filtering stuff
        for (U child : root.getSubElements()){
            U cleanChild = recursiveFilter(child); //Here comes the problem, it says reursiveFilter can only accept T but now we are sending U != T
        }
        return filteredRoot;
    }
}
```

I am sending U (child of T) to the function for the current iteration, but U become T in the next one, and then it will send U, its child, to the following, and so...

Comment: I'm not sure on the technical reason, but this is ambiguous. There isn't a need for `U`. Just use T.

Comment: But they are not the same type. T is the parent sublass of XMLElement and U is the chikd suclass of XMLElement. In other words, T.getSubElements() can never return a List of <<T>>

Comment: Just to clarify, in `XMLElement<U>`, the type parameter `U` is a bound on the types of the child elements?

Comment: Can you give a small overview of some classes you have? I think I don't completely understand your design.

Comment: Im not exatly sure what do you mean, but if you mean that any child is always type U then this is for sure given the outer architetre not show here.

Comment: If I change U for T it compiles but I cannot understand why, because not all the T will correspond to same subclass

Comment: I tried to make up the meaning from your code but I can't.  It will be great if you can show us a bit on your XMLElement, especially for what is the meaning of the type param of XMLElement

Comment: XMLElement is an abstract class defined as XMLElement<T extends XMLElement>. Any subclass is a XMLParticularElement extends XMLElement<OtherXMLParticularElement extends XMLElement<?>>

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use:

```
private static <T extends XMLElement<T>> T recursiveFilter(T root) {
    T filteredRoot = root;
    //Some filtering stuff
    for (T child : root.getSubElements()) {
        T cleanChild = recursiveFilter(child);
    }
    return filteredRoot;
}
```

Comment: Overlooked it, sorry. But you don't need a `U` in the method, so you can replace it with `?`, can't you?

Comment: root.getSubelements() returns childs which are a different type from T. Indeed return U where U is -> T extends XMLElement<U>

Comment: Why do you define U here? This is the same as not using U and just have T

Comment: Because T is the parent subclass and U the child subclass which is what defines T . A subclass of XMLElement<?> is always XMLElement<Concrete type, lets call U>

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is:

```
T extends XMLElement<U>, U extends XMLElement<?>
```

Thus `T` is of type `XMLElement` or one of its subtypes.
And `U` is of type `XMLElement` or one of its subtypes.

In summary, `T` and `U` are the same type, and as far as I can see you should be able to simplify the definition to

```
private static <T extends XMLElement<T>> T recursiveFilter(T root) {
  //...
}
```

At least I know that this compiles fine to me:

```
static <T extends XMLElement<T>> T recursiveFilter(T root){
    T filteredRoot = root;
    for(T child: root.getSubElements()){
        T cleanChild = recursiveFilter(child);
    }
    return filteredRoot;
}

interface XMLElement<T> {
    List<T> getSubElements();
}
```

Comment: You are right, the definition of T is exatly the same as U, both are a subclass X of common class, but they dont correspond to the same particular subclass so T.getClass()!=U.getClass() but both are X extend XMLElement, definition is identical. Moreover T extends XMLElement<U> but not the opposite. The compiler gives error if i try to call your funtion beause there is no subclass defined as T extending XMlElement<T>, so they hold its own type as a inner type